# xlsx file extension not valid after saving with openpyxl and keep_vba=true. Which is the best way?

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

In the environment, we have an excel file, which includes rawdata in one sheet and pivot table and charts in another sheet.

I need to append rows every day to raw data automatically using a python job.
I am not sure, but there may be some VB Script running on the front end which will refresh the pivot tables.

I used openpyxl and by following its online documentation, I was able to append rows and save the workbook. I used keep_vba=true while loading the workbook to keep the VBA modules inside to enable pivoting. But after saving the workbook, the xlsx is not being opened anymore using MS office and saying the format or the extension is not valid. I can see the data using python but with office, its not working anymore. If I don't use keep_vba=true, then pivoting is not working, only the previous values are present (ofcourse as I understood, as VBA script is needed for pivoting).

Could you explain me what's happening? I am new to python and don't know its concepts much.

How can I fix this in openpyxl or is there any better alternative other than openpyxl. Data connections in MS office is not an option for me.

As I understood, xlsx may need special modules to save the VB script to save in the same way as it may be saved using MS office. If it is, then what is the purpose of keep_vba=true ?

I would be grateful if you could explain in more detail. I would love to know.

As I have very short time to complete this task, I am looking for a quick answer here, instead of going through all the concepts.

Thankyou!

Comment: I am not bothered about charts, but the pivoting functions should not be lost.

Comment: `I used keep_vba=true while loading the workbook to keep the VBA modules inside to enable pivoting.` Well, `.xlsx` file do not have have macro in them so I am not sure how is that possible?

Comment: Ok, so how can I make pivoting works??

Answer (score 3):

You have to save the files with the extension ".xlsm" rather than ".xlsx". The .xlsx format exists specifically to provide the user with assurance that there is no VBA code within the file. This is an Excel standard and not a problem with openpyxl. With that said, I haven't worked with openpyxl, so I'm not sure what you need to do to be sure your files are properly converted to .xlsm.

Edit: Sorry, misread your question first time around. Easiest step would be to set keep_vba=False. That might resolve your issue right there, since you're telling openpyxl to look for VBA code that can't possibly exist in an xlsx file. Hard to say more than that until you post the relevant section of your code.

Comment: But the file was xlsx, not xlsm and pivoting is there and as Siddharth Rout said pivoting doesn't need VBA. So how can I make pivoting work here?

Comment: keep_vba=false works, but pivoting is not working. Only the pivot table values are pasted.